# Docker Swarm loop

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have written my own simple docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/briomkez/ethereum-test). It works fine.

Then I created my docker swarm with only two nodes a master and a slave and started a service with the following command:

`docker service create  --mode global --name benchmark briomkez/ethereum-test`

It loops, because it cannot create the service (the default command is a simple `ls`).

Why does this happen? Is it expected?

If I run the same service with a different command, e.g.:

`docker service create  --mode global --name benchmark briomkez/ethereum-test geth`

It works like a charm. Is this behavior expected, what is the motivation for the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers are isolated applications. When the application that it launches exits, the container also exits. So when your command is `ls`, that will run and then exit almost immediately, stopping the container.

Swarm mode has the goal to maintain a target state for your containers. By default, it will keep a single replica (instance of a container) of the service running. If the current state does not match the target state, it will take action to correct the issue. So for a container that has no running instances and a target replica count of 1, it will be constantly started.

So yes, this is an expected behavior given the inputs. Instead of `ls`, you should be using a long running daemon process.